# Can you create collapsible #Region like scopes in C++ within VS 2008?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, pragma, readability

I miss it so much (used it a lot in C#). can you do it in C++?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, you can. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6xkz944(VS.80).aspx).

```
#pragma region Region_Name
//Your content.
#pragma endregion Region_Name
```

Answer (score 1):

The Visual assist add-in for VC supports regions for c++. Don't know if 2008 has build in regions for C++ though.

Answer (score 1):

For the VBers:

```
#Region "identifier_string" 
' Your content
#End Region
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd032a17.aspx